# Is there an R Package allowing me to use Anderson Darling Upper tail test?

Tags: r, package

I am struggling with implementing the R function **Anderson Darling Upper Tail Test**.

The traditional Anderson Darling Test works fine with function **ad_test()**, but the Anderson Darling Upper Tail Test **adup.test()** is not working.

I have tried installing packages "truncgof" and "adklakedata", but both are not running and I have installed latest R Version

Is there any other package/function I may try?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say `adup.test()` doesn't work, do you mean you get an error or an unexpected outcome?

Comment: I cannot ven run it. This is the message " library(truncgof)
Error in library(truncgof) : there is no package called ‘truncgof’". I was wondering if there was another function or package

Comment: It looks like `truncgof` was removed from CRAN back in May as they couldn't contact the maintainer.  You could either try manually installing an older version from the archive, or take a look at the code and see if you can create your own function for it.

Comment: You can access the source here: https://rdrr.io/cran/truncgof/f/ - I think from a quick glance the mctest.R and adup.test.R contents may be sufficent. (adup.test()) calls mctest internally).

Comment: Thanks! Can I use the following instead of mctest "https://rdrr.io/cran/truncgof/src/R/ad2up.test.R"? It should be the code for AD Upper Tail, as from truncgof function

Comment: Worth a try I think - I'm not familiar with the original test, I just looked up the package.